# Connect SQL Server To GSheets with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, google-sheets

I am trying to pass the data from a DB on the SQL Server to GSheets, we are talking about more than 800k records, the first part of the connection when doing a Print works correctly for me, but when I try to put them in the sheet everything fails , I have been trying several things but it does not throw me these errors

```
import pyodbc
import gspread
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import rquests
import json

server = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 1433'
database = 'DATADB'
username = 'XXX_XX'
password = 'PASSWORDXXX'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.cosillastabla")

rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'kjsdfkjfjksdjkfsdfsdhfsdkjfhsjf'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

sheet = service.spreadsheets()

request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId = SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range = 'temilla!B2:B180', valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body={"values": rows}).execute()

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
   request.append_row(i+2, row)

cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

This is the print of data

```
(734206, 'xxxxx', Decimal('28.8000'), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 29, 13, 5, 17, 903000), 695856, 27818, 12, Decimal('0'), 350)
(734207, 'Tarjeta', Decimal('1.0000'), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 29, 13, 7, 56, 577000), 695857, 27808, 2, Decimal('0'), 120)
(734208, 'xxxx', Decimal('12.9000'), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 29, 13, 8, 48, 977000), 695858, 27814, 12, Decimal('0'), 365)
(734209, 'Efectivo', Decimal('10.9000'), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 29, 13, 9, 50, 23000), 695859, 27815, 1, Decimal('0'), 120)
(734210, 'xxxx', Decimal('19.9000'), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 29, 13, 14, 59, 223000), 695860, 27821, 12, Decimal('0'), 414)
```

This is the error

```
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable
```

These are the data that I am trying to take to sheets, but no matter how hard I try, I can't get it

[image]

I can't find the way to format the data so that it goes to sheets

Comment: Why have you formatted all your text as code?

Comment: I don't usually use the editor to ask questions, sorry, I've already corrected it